# Horizontal to vertical table

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

how to convert my horizontal to vertical table? My current table is like this:

[image]

i want to change is like this:

[image]

This is my code. I use looping to fetch the data from spreadsheet. I try so many time but got error

```
 //CREATE THE DATA TABLE
  function createTable(dataArray) {
var array=[];//store all the table
if(dataArray && dataArray !== undefined && dataArray.length != 0){     

  for(var i=0; i<dataArray.length; i++) {
 var result = "<table class='table table-sm table-striped' id='dtable' style='font-size:0.5em'>"+
   "<thead style='white-space: nowrap'>"+
      "<tr>"+
      "<th colspan=13><center><img src=''style='width:80px;margin-top:8px'><br><br></center></th>"+
       "</tr>"+
     "<tr>"+                 
      "<th scope='col'>Timestamp</th>"+
      "<th scope='col'>Work Order</th>"+
      "<th scope='col'>Cable/Wire/Tube SAP Part Number</th>"+
      "<th scope='col'>Measurement Record</th>"+
      "<th scope='col'>Equipment ID</th>"+
    "</tr>"+
  "</thead><tr>";
  for(var j=0; j<dataArray[i].length; j++){
  

  result += "<td>"+dataArray[i][j]+"</td>";
  }
  result += "</tr></table>";
  array.push(result);
  }
 // result += "</table>";
  var div = document.getElementById('search-results');
console.log(array);
  div.innerHTML = array;
}else{
  var div = document.getElementById('search-results');
  //div.empty()
  div.innerHTML = "Data not found!";
}
  }
</script>
        <!--##JAVASCRIPT FUNCTIONS ~ END ------------------- -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function createTable(dataArray) {
  var array = [];
  var headerCol = ["Timestamp","Work Order","Cable/Wire/Tube SAP Part Number","Measurement Record","Equipment ID"];
  if (dataArray && dataArray !== undefined && dataArray.length != 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
      var result = "<table class='table table-sm table-striped' id='dtable' style='font-size:0.5em'>" +
        "<thead style='white-space: nowrap'>" +
        "<tr>" +
        "<th colspan=13><center><img src=''style='width:80px;margin-top:8px'><br><br></center></th>" +
        "</tr>" +
        "<tr>" +
        "<th scope='col'>Header1</th>" +
        "<th scope='col'>Header2</th>" +
        "</tr>" +
        "</thead>";
      for (var j = 0; j < headerCol.length; j++) {
        result += "<tr><td>" + headerCol[j] + "</td><td>" + dataArray[i][j] + "</td></tr>";
      }
      result += "</table>";
      array.push(result);
    }
    var div = document.getElementById('search-results');
    div.innerHTML = array.join("");
  } else {
    var div = document.getElementById('search-results');
    div.innerHTML = "Data not found!";
  }
}

// This is a sample value for testing.
createTable([["A1","B1","C1","D1","E1"],["A2","B2","C2","D2","E2"],["A3","B3","C3","D3","E3"]]);
```

```html
<div id="search-results"></div>
```

- In this sample, `Header1` and `Header2` are used. If you don't want to remove it, please remove it from the above script.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can "rotate" your table

```js
let input = document.getElementById("input");
let outputTbody = document.getElementById("output").querySelector("tbody");
let th = input.querySelectorAll("th");
let td = input.querySelectorAll("td");
let trs = [];
for (let i = 0; i < th.length; i++) {
    trs.push(`<tr><td>${th[i].innerHTML}</td><td>${td[i].innerHTML}</td></tr>`);
}
outputTbody.innerHTML = trs.join("");
```

```html
<table id="input">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>a</th>
            <th>b</th>
            <th>c</th>
            <th>d</th>
            <th>e</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table id="output">
    <thead>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>value</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```